# Install Sub-Dependencies when Using Local Dependencies / Sub-Import Paths

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to import local modules to a project.

Structure is like this:

```
project
- dependency: module1
```

```
module1
- dependency: lodash
```

So..
`project < module1 < lodash`

Now my `project`'s package.json is like this:

```
"dependencies": {
   "module1": "file:../trunk/module1"
}
```

And `module1`'s package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   "lodash": "^4.17.0"
}
```

Now the issue is, when I do an `npm install` on `project`, it only installs `module1`, without its dependencies (`lodash`, in this example).

I also tried using `sub-path import` and the behavior is the same.

```
"imports": {
  "#mod1": {
    "node": "module1",
    "default": "../trunk/module1"
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "module1": "^1.0.0"
},
```

Then calling it as:

```
import { SampleFunction } from '#mod1'
```

Both solutions above only creates a symbolic link of the local dependency `module1` -- which does not have a local node_modules because I didn't do an `npm install` on the dependency. I am looking for a cleaner solution - I do not want to go manually do an `npm install` on all sub-dependencies.

How can I make npm download all sub-dependencies when importing a local module?

Thanks!

Comment: Also looking for the answer to this question.